# exclude files from jblack Lint - jupyter notebook black lint

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, lint

I am trying to use jblack to format .ipynb files in the main dot (.) source directory.

`jblack` is like 'black' but for jupyter notebooks instead of normal python files.
https://github.com/irahorecka/jupyterblack

I did `jblack .` to format all the .ipynb files in the main directory BUT it also caught my .venv folder.

with `black` I can exclude the .venv folder by using a `pyproject.toml` and adding an exclude value with regex like so:

```
[tool.black]
extend-exclude = '''

(
      \.eggs
    | \.git
    | \.hg
    | \.mypy_cache
    | \.tox
    | \.venv
    | _build
    | app.py
    | buck-out
    | build
    | dist
  )
'''
```

I tried adding that file to my directory to see if `jblack` can use a `pyproject.toml` file like `black` can.

Is there anyway to exclude folders for `jblack`? Is there a black or lint alternative that can autoformate like jblack but exclude specific folders like black?